# OpenGL drawing meshes incorrectly

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm attempting to make an OpenGL Engine in C++, but cannot render meshes correctly. Meshes, when rendered, create faces that connect two random points on the mesh, or a random point on the mesh with 0,0,0.

The problem can be seen here:

[image: Corrupted Wireframe Rendering]

(I made it a wireframe to see the problem more clearly)

Code:

```
// Render all meshes (Graphics.cpp)
for( int curMesh = 0; curMesh < numMesh; curMesh++ ) {
    // Save pointer of buffer
    meshes[curMesh]->updatebuf();
    Buffer buffer = meshes[curMesh]->buffer;

    // Update model matrix
    glm::mat4 mvp = Proj*View*(meshes[curMesh]->model);

    // Initialize vertex array
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertbuffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*buffer.numcoords*3, meshes[curMesh]->verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Pass information to shader
    GLuint posID = glGetAttribLocation( shader, "s_vPosition" );
    glVertexAttribPointer( posID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( posID );
    
    // Check if texture applicable
    if( meshes[curMesh]->texID != NULL && meshes[curMesh]->uvs != NULL ) {
        // Initialize uv array
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer );
        glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*buffer.numcoords*2, meshes[curMesh]->uvs, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

        // Pass information to shader
        GLuint uvID = glGetAttribLocation( shader, "s_vUV" );
        glVertexAttribPointer( uvID, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(0) );        
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( uvID );
        
        // Set mesh texture
        glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, meshes[curMesh]->texID );
        GLuint texID = glGetUniformLocation( shader, "Sampler" );
        glUniform1i( texID, 0 );
    }

    // Actiavte shader
    glUseProgram( shader );
        
    // Set MVP matrix
    GLuint mvpID = glGetUniformLocation( shader, "MVP" );
    glUniformMatrix4fv( mvpID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0] );

    // Draw verticies on screen
    bool wireframe = true;
    if( wireframe )
        for(int i = 0; i < buffer.numcoords; i += 3)
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, i, 3);
    else
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, buffer.numcoords );
}
// Mesh Class (Graphics.h)
class mesh {
public:
    mesh();
    void updatebuf();
    Buffer buffer;
    GLuint texID;
    bool updated;

    GLfloat* verts;
    GLfloat* uvs;

    glm::mat4 model;
};
```

My Obj loading code is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdcpg4vok11lf9d/ObjReader.txt (It's pretty crude and isn't organized, but should still work)

Comment: Can you post your example file? You make a bunch of assumptions in your loader that may or may not be respected by the data, but without the data it's hard to tell.

Comment: @DirkR Perhaps that might be the problem, here is the teapot.obj file I'm using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8fy46x3zeadg0s/teapot.obj.txt

Comment: Hm, ok, that one is about as trivial as possible, that should work. So really my recommendation is to just drop your own loader and use assimp (http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) instead, which supports a lot more formats and is widely used.

Comment: Writing your own loader that works isn't impossible, though. I'd carefully inspect the data and see if the buffer contents are what you expect. It's tedious, but you'll definitely find the root cause that way. One common mistake often made is not shifting the indices by 1 (OpenGL counts from 0, OBJ from 1). I'd try to manually remove some faces from the object file to only leave the problematic vertices, and then confirm that the VBO actually has the correct data first.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a primitive restart issue to me. Hard to tell what exactly is the problem without seeing some code. It would help a lot to see the about 20 lines above and below and including the drawing calls render the teapot. I.e. the 20 lines before the corresponding glDrawArrays, glDrawElements or glBegin call and the 20 lines after.

Comment: I thought it would have something to do with restarting the triangles, but there is nothing in the OBJ file to signify a vertex breaking point so how would I know when a new triangle list begins? (I posted the code btw)

Answer (score 1):

subtract 1 from the indices for your use, since these are 1-based indices, and you will almost certainly need 0-based indices.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your triangles are not connected for the wireframe to look perfect.
In case triangles is not connected you should construct index buffer.